# Tuple looping (I think)

Tags: python

I have this code for a quiz but only the first question appears.  I can answer the first question and the score will adjust accordingly however the next question never appears.  I have tried researching looping through tuples and have played around with my code but to no avail.  I am a Python newbie and would appreciate some help please. I have spent hours on it believe me.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("End of year exam")

score = 0

def submit_button_clicked():
    global score
    global questions

    score = 0
    if answer.get() == questions[0][1]:
        score+=1
    else:
        score = score
    scoretxt.config(text = "Your score is: {}".format(str(score)))


questions =[("What does 13 + 5 = ?","18"),("What does 12 + 8 = ?","20"),("What does 19 + 6 = ?","25"),("What does 17 + 15 = ?","32")]

Label(root,text = "Question : ",bg ="light grey").grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = W)
question=Label(root,bg = "light green",text= questions[1][0], width = 38)
question.grid(row =1,column=0)

Label(root,text = "Answer: ",bg = "light grey").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
answer = Entry(root,bg ="white",width = 45, justify = CENTER)
answer.grid(row = 3,column=0)

scoretxt = Label(root,text ="Your score is:",bg = "light green", width = 38)
scoretxt.grid(row = 10,column = 0, sticky = W)

### make a submit button
Button(root,text= "Submit",bg = "light grey",command = submit_button_clicked).grid(row = 4,column = 0, sticky = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "only the first question appears".. Hmm, could it be because you only do `questions[1][0]`?

Comment: I know questions[1][0] would make it display the first question but I'm not sure how to amend the code so that it displays the next question, say, when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: I don't know how to change the label text in Tkinter, but you could keep a global variable for which question you are currently asking. When you answer the question correctly, you can increment that counter, and reset the text in the label.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I added a `try` statement in the function `submit_button_clicked()` so if the question was the last one it would still update the score.  If you read through the code you should see what I changed. Let me no if you don't understand it. Have a great day!

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("End of year exam")

score = 0

questions =[("What does 13 + 5 = ?","18"),("What does 12 + 8 = ?","20"),("What does 19 + 6 = ?","25"),("What does 17 + 15 = ?","32")]

current_question = 0

def submit_button_clicked():
    global score
    global questions
    global current_question

    if answer.get() == questions[current_question][1]:
        score += 1
        current_question += 1
        try:
            question.config(text=questions[current_question][0])
        except:
            pass
        answer.delete(0, 'end')
    scoretxt.config(text = "Your score is: {}".format(str(score)))




Label(root,text = "Question : ",bg ="light grey").grid(row = 0,column = 0, sticky = W)
question=Label(root,bg = "light green",text=questions[current_question][0], width = 38)
question.grid(row =1,column=0)

Label(root,text = "Answer: ",bg = "light grey").grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
answer = Entry(root,bg ="white",width = 45, justify = CENTER)
answer.grid(row = 3,column=0)

scoretxt = Label(root,text ="Your score is:",bg = "light green", width = 38)
scoretxt.grid(row = 10,column = 0, sticky = W)

### make a submit button
Button(root,text= "Submit",bg = "light grey",command = submit_button_clicked).grid(row = 4,column = 0, sticky = W)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: An explanation of how your code is different would make this a better answer. Is it is, the reader has to compare your code line-by-line to the original to see what you changed.

Comment: Personally, I don't mind having to go through the code line by line to find differences as it helps with my understanding, however, I could see some people not wanting to do this.. Thank you very much everyone for your help.

Comment: If this solved your problem I would appreciate if you would accept my answer. Thanks!